# How to find the area between two polar curves?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

I am working on this problem [Evaluating the area between the curves $r=2\sin\theta$ and $r=\sin\theta+\cos\theta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500280/evaluating-the-area-between-the-curves-r-2-sin-theta-and-r-sin-theta-cos-th).

[image]

I need to find the area of the larger circle outside the smaller circle.
It is enough to find area of the part of a smaller circle which is inside the larger circle. My doubt is to how to find the limits for $\theta$. Or, is there any alternative way to do the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that both $r = \sin\theta + \cos\theta$ and $r = 2 \sin\theta ~ $ circles form between $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$ and to find their intersection point,

$r = \sin\theta + \cos\theta = 2 \sin\theta \implies \theta = \pi /4$

So one of the approaches will be to find the area bound by individual curves as in the below diagram and then subtract the smaller area from the larger area.

[image]

Please note that the section of $r \leq  \sin\theta + \cos\theta$ (smaller circle) shown in the diagram forms for $\pi/4 \leq \theta \leq 3\pi/4$ whereas the section of $r \leq 2 \sin\theta$ (larger circle) shown in the diagram forms for $\pi/4 \leq \theta \leq \pi$.

So the integral can be written as,

$A_l = \displaystyle \frac{1}{2} \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi} (2 \sin \theta)^2 ~ d\theta$

$A_s = \displaystyle \frac{1}{2} \int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4} (\sin \theta + \cos\theta)^2 ~ d\theta$

and desired area $A = A_l - A_s$.